# What is "length" specified in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android

I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the below format while executing my Android code.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=-1
```

This format is coming only when I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in Android. In Java, I am just getting the index printed.

My question is, in the above statement, what does length signify to?

Is it capacity of `ArrayList` or size of `ArrayList`?

Comment: Default size of ArrayList is 16 so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=-1

**length** indicates the size of the array
**index** indicates the illegal index for which the [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) was thrown.

- Size of the array is 16
- Valid indexes are 0 - 15
- Invalid index which was attempted to be accessed is "-1"

> Is it capacity of ArrayList or size of ArrayList?

It is the [size](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) of the [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

The *size* indicates the number of elements in that list; whereas, the *capacity*  indicates how many elements can be potentially accommodated in the ArrayList without reallocating its internal structures.

Answer (score 4):

It stands for the size of the array, which is `16` so it goes from `0` to `15`. However, you are trying to access the element in position `-1`, which of course does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Length relates to the number of elements in the ArrayList object (currently stored inside it). If length is n elements long then the length goes from zero to n - 1

Hope that helps :)